# Make it one line, even if <br> is there

Tags: html, css, break, line-breaks

How to make a `<p>` tag in one line, even if there is page break `<br>`?

For example:

```
<p> some text<br> some text<br> some text</p>
```

How can we keep the above in one line by using only CSS?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @MichaelHancock I sometimes do this if I have an address partial that I use in multiple places - sometimes it would need to be over multiple lines, sometimes it needs to be all on one line, it's easier to change the style depending on where it is rather than use multiple address partials as if the address ever changed, you would only need to change it in one place rather than multiple places

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the `br` by adding `display:none` and add `white-space: nowrap;` to the p :

```css
br {
  display: none;
}

p {
  white-space: nowrap;

  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p> some text<br> some text<br> some text</p>
```

I added a small width and border to show you that it will always remain in one line, you can remove them.

Comment: But I can not do that, as it is coming from other ends. I have only Id. I can only write css for ID.

Comment: @Baktha yes you can do this with id also, you have the id of p ?

Comment: @Baktha if you have id of p you can for example do this `p#id br {}` and `p#id { }`

Comment: for example an adress:

VV street
Tambaram
Chennai.

the above is coming from the third party. But I have only ID. In that ID if I give, text-align: center. It coming in center. as like that i want to disable the break by writing CSS in ID only

Comment: @Baktha in this case simply do this `#id p br {}` and `#id p { }`. Then the style will applied only inside the #id

Comment: @Baktha try my previous comment and tell me if it works. If not try this `#id br` {} and `#id { }`. Simply add the id before the rules i defined

Answer (score 3):

Simple,

```css
br {
    content: " ";
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<p> some text<br> some text<br> some text</p>
```

Comment: But I can not do that, as it is coming from other ends. I have only Id. I can only write css for ID.

Comment: @Baktha they inside div?

Comment: for example an adress:

VV street
Tambaram
Chennai.

the above is coming from the third party. But I have only ID. In that ID if I give, text-align: center. It coming in center. as like that i want to disable the break by writing CSS in ID only